# How to prove this expression of the specific heat in statistical physics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, partition-function

Where does thes expression come from?

$c_v=\pi^2/3\cdot k_B^2\cdot g(E_F)$

where $g(E_F)$ is the density of state

Comment: Where did you find  that expression?

Answer (score 1):

This is Sommerfeld expansion for the thermal capacity of the electron gas. The right formula is actually $\pi^2/3 k_{\mathrm{B}}^2 g(E_{\mathrm{F}}) T$ (you forgot the $T$).

It comes from the expansion of the energy of the gas:

$$u = \int \frac{g(\varepsilon) \varepsilon}{e^{\beta (\varepsilon - \mu)}+1}d \varepsilon$$ at low temperature ($\beta \gg \mu$) and around $\mu$.

This does not give you the right result on its own, as you have to take into account the variation of $\mu$ with temperature by writing the same expansion for $n$ (density of particles), and equating the first term of the expansion to zero.

See this wikipedia page for an outline of the calculation: 
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_heat_capacity

Comment: Yes, that $T$ is important, it is the linear term in the low-temperature heat capacity of metals; $c_v$ must go to zero at low temperature (Nernst's law).